# Foundation calculus doubt

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have an ODE in the following form:
$\frac{dx}{d\text{t}} = f(\text{m}) sin\text{z}$

where z = z(t) and m = m(t) i.e. they are both functions of time, t.
Now, if I were to concern

It is possible to rewrite the above ODE as

$k\frac{dx}{d\text{z}} = f(\text{m}) sin\text{z}$

where $k$ is a constant. My question is the following:

Since 'm' is only a function of 't' but not 'z', could I solve the ode by doing the following:

$\int dx = \frac{f(\text{m})}{k} \int sin\text{z}   d\text{z}$

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. How did you arrive from the first line to the second line?

Comment: There is a modelling assumption made in my research that definies 'z' as a linear function of 't'. Further, 'm' is also assumed to be a linear function of 't'.

Comment: Actually, I think I found my error (Thanks to Dylan's comment if I did). let me explain my train of thought:



If, $x = x(m(t),z(t))$, then



$\dot x = \frac{\partial x}{\partial m} \dot m + \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\dot z + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$



I incorrectly deleted some steps in my solution which made it seem like $\frac{d}{dt} = k \frac{d}{dz}$ whereas it should be

$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial m} \dot m + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\dot z + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But... I still don't know how to go abbout solving for $x$ even after all this. I'd be very grateful for any help/direction, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is not true.  First, I assume your $*$ denotes multiplication, and not convolution.  Write everything out with the variables intact; $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(m(t))\sin(z(t))$$  If $m$ and $z$ are linear in $t$ (as per your earlier comment), we can write $m(t)=\alpha t$, $z(t)=\beta t$.  The right hand side is a function of $t$ alone; $t\mapsto f(m(t))\sin(z(t)).$  The general solution is given by the antiderivative of the right hand side.

$$x=\int\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int f(\alpha t)\sin(\beta t)dt.$$  If you want to solve this equation by integration with respect to $z$ as you have written, then write $m=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}z$ and $t=\frac{1}{\beta}z$.  Then, by the chain rule, $$\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{dz}=f\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}z\right)\cdot(\sin z)\frac{1}{\beta}.$$  Separating variables, you get $$\int dx=\frac{1}{\beta}\int f\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}z\right)\sin zdz.$$  You cannot factor out the $f$ because it depends on $z$.  This is the error in your solution.

Comment: Hey Kevin,

Thanks a lot for correcting the incorrect use of *. Bad programming habits creep through while writing math :) However, your steps make a lot of sense to me and was extremely helpful.

It has, however, led me to another question: is there someway I can determine $x$, using the definition of a total derivative based on my comment above.

Comment: I don't think so.  Why can't you just solve it using the method I outlined above?  If your differential equation really is so simple, a quadrature (integration) will provide a solution.

Comment: So the thing is the equation that I actually have to sovle is a little more 'involved' once you substiue for the $f$.

$f(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}z) = {constant}/{z^n}$, which makes the integral that you wrote in the RHS of the last equation you wrote a variant of a Sine integral, if I'm not mistaken. For now, I've ended up using a symbolic solver in Mathematica but I think that there must be a way to solve that integral using the total derivative. Maybe an approximation of some kind can be made to solve for it....? My engineering math knowledge is kind of limited is what I'm starting to realize.

Comment: Well, if the integral in the last equation is a variant of the Sine integral, then your explicit solution is going to not be an elementary function, no matter how you solve it.  Maybe there's a change of variables that will allow you to write it in a way that it can be solved implicitly, but of course, there are limitations there as well.  I'll be honest, I have never in my life used the total derivative to solve anything.  You might look up "total differential equation", since this seems to be what you're asking about.  My experience with these is minimal.

Comment: Depending on the application, perhaps some kind of approximation method might be useful?  Do you need to know how the solution behaves globally?  At a specific value of $t$?  In the limit as $t$ becomes large?

Comment: Globally. 

Also, you've been immensely helpful; always good to have someone to talk to about this kinda stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23004/discussion-between-kevin-church-and-gadha007).